# Regex to match a pattern only if its length is bigger than a value

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

I have 2 strings and want to know

1. if string 2 have a subset of the characters of string 1 on the
   same order
2. this subset has a minimun size determined by me.

For example:

```
string 1 = stackoverflow
<br>minimun size = 5

string 2a = stack (MATCH)
string 2b = stac  (DO NOT MATCH)
string 2c = staov (MATCH)
string 2d = staZov (DO NOT MATCH)
string 2e = eflow (MATCH) 
string 2f = ewolf (DO NOT MATCH)
string 2g = somethingstacksomething (MATCH)
```

I am building the regex programatically, so the first part of the problem could be solved with the expression: `(s)?(t)?(a)?(c)?(k)?(o)?(v)?(e)?(r)?(f)?(l)?(o)?(w)?`

But i can't figure out how to apply the "minimun character" rule. Is it possible to do it using regex?

thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added another example to complete the problem specification. Also, if you want to know, this is part of a method to evaluate the password strength specified by a user. If he defines a password derived from some other information (login, born date, name, etc) we should warn him.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this with regex?  It doesn't seem very efficient that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a lookahead that ensures that there are five characters: `(?=.{5})s?t?a?c?k?o?v?e?r?f?l?o?w?`

Comment: For one moment i think it could solve it but then a realized that strings such as "stac1" are matched too.

Comment: You can fix that by anchoring the regex: `^...$`

Comment: You are right @SLarks but now i saw that my problem's description was not complete at all. The string 2 (the one to be tested) must match if a substring of it is according to regex so anchoring will not resolve it. I will correct my fault and change the original post.

Comment: @marcel: Put the optional chars in a group, then check the group's length if the regex matches.  `(s?t?a?c?k?o?v?e?r?f?l?o?w?)`;  `if (match.Groups[1].Length > 5)`

Answer (score 2):

> But i can't figure out how to apply the "minimun character" rule.

After you determine the possible matches.  You need to determine the length of the result.

You can simply use **String.Length** to determine that.

Comment: Yes, on my code i do something like that. In my case i have to iterate through every match and see the Length. I am just looking for some way to do this "size check" at regex stage, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! There is a way to do it, (but you aren't going to like it). It results in a potentially large (and possibly slow) regex. Assuming `string1` is `ABCD`. Then here are the regexes for all the different length requirements:

```cs
length  = 4;
regex = @"
  ABCD
  ";

length  = 3;
regex = @"
    ABCD?
  | ABC?D
  | AB?CD
  | A?BCD
  ";

length  = 2;
regex = @"
    ABC?D?
  | AB?CD?
  | AB?C?D
  | A?BCD?
  | A?BC?D
  | A?B?CD
  ";

length  = 1
regex = @"
  [ABCD]
  ";
```

I haven't thought through the way you would go about assembling this programmatically, but I'm sure that it can be done. However, a large regex having lots of OR'ed alternatives may likely be slower that using the *"match then check the length of the matched string"* method you are currently using.

I scratched my head for quite a while on this one and I'm pretty sure there is no simple/clever regex construct that does what you are asking.